# Java - Inspect an open URL Connection and obtain IP address

Tags: java, dns, connection, recaptcha

We are having sporadic Connection Time Out issues connecting to Google for ReCaptcha in our Java application. I know that there are other questions about this general issue on SO, but my question here is slightly different. I'd like to know if there is a way to inspect the URLConnection we have open to determine what IP address it's actually trying to connect to. We suspect some combination of firewall/DNS issues but what we'd really like to do is to log the IP address that was actually resolving for the host for any timeout that we receive.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain their reason for doing so?

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest case, you can do a DNS lookup on the host name in the URL:

```
String hostname = urlConnection.getURL().getHost();
String ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(hostname).getHostAddress();
```

If you need to know all the IP addresses to which HTTP redirects may have led, you’ll need to call `setInstanceFollowRedirects(false)` and handle them yourself:

```
HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnection;
httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);

while (true) {
    String hostname = urlConnection.getURL().getHost();
    String ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(hostname).getHostAddress();

    System.out.printf("%s resolves to %s%n", hostname, ipAddress);

    if (httpConn.getResponseCode() / 100 != 3) {
        break;
    }

    String newURL = httpConn.getHeaderField("Location");
    if (newURL == null) {
        break;
    }

    urlConnection = new URL(newURL).openConnection();

    httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnection;
    httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks - the issue with this approach is that it allows for timing issues. I didn't give a ton of detail in my original question, but what we suspect is occurring is a slight timing issue in which our Java code is resolving to one IP but our domain-based firewall milliseconds later is resolving to a different set of IPs and therefore blocking the connection.  (continued in next comment...)

Comment: (continued from previous comment) ... We're considering doing something like what you proposed in case it does shed light on a case where the DNS cache in the application is more out of sync with the firewall cache, but I was kind of hoping there was a way to get the IP on the open connection itself so we can be 100% certain that this is the IP it was resolving to.